# Multisort using Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, array-multisort

My data is in the form of:

```
a = [
      {
        "a_id":101,
        "a_value":100000.0,
        "a_quantity":360.0
      },
      {
        "a_id":108,
        "a_value":110000.0,
        "a_quantity":210.0
      },
      {
        "a_id":104,
        "a_value":105000.0,
        "a_quantity":310.0
      }
    ]
```

I would like the data to be sorted in descending order of `a_value`. I have tried:

```
a.sort_by {|k| k[:a_value] }.reverse
```

But it does not get sorted.

Comment: You sort it, but this does not change `a`. If you want to modify `a` you must use the bang version of sort: `sort_by! `.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. For me, it gets sorted just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have works. Just don't forget to assign the sorted collection to a variable (`sort_by` and `reverse` do not change the collection).

Bonus: here's arguably a nicer version (one pass, instead of two)

```
a.sort_by{ |v| -v[:a_value] }
```